# Calculate the number of different ways of tiling 'special' rooms [Read Full Que. Below]

Tags: logic, contest-math, problem-solving

It's a really long question so please bear with me. I will write my approach in the comments since the question is already so big.

You have to tile a room that is two units wide and N units long.  You have with you two types of tiles: a rectangle that is one unit wide and two units long, and an L-shaped tile covering three square units.  Here are pictures of the two types of tiles.

[image]

You are allowed to rotate the tiles when you lay them.  You have an infinite supplyof both types of tiles.  However, your architect is from Nauru and is a believer in thePolynesian system of tiling calledBatlar  Guntuwhich forbids any corner where fourtiles meet.For instance, here are some ways to tile a 2×4 room.  The first three are consistentwith theBatlar Guntusystem while the fourth tiling is not

[image]

Your  task  is  to  calculate  the  number  of  different  ways  a  room  can  be  tiled  withoutviolating the principles ofBatlar Guntu.  For instance, a 2×3 room can be tiled in 5different ways, as follows:

[image]

Calculate the number of different ways of tiling rooms of the following sizes:

- a) 2 x 8
- b) 2 x 10
- c) 2 x 12

Answer (score 2):

Any such tiling will be built out of these block patterns:

[image]

with the rules

- There are no adjacent $B$ blocks (the only way to have 4 corners together)
- $E$ can only be followed by $F$ or $G$
- $F$ can only follow $E$ or $F$ and only be followed by $F$ or $G$
- $G$ can only follow $E$ or $F$
- $H$ can only be followed by $I$ or $J$
- $I$ can only follow $H$ or $I$ and only be followed by $I$ or $J$
- $J$ can only follow $H$ or $I$

From this you can build some recursion formulas:. Let $a_n$ be the number of tilings for a $2\times n$ room, and let $b_n$ be the number of tilings that do not end with a $B$ block. Setting $a_n =b_n = 0$ for $n < 0$, and $a_0 = b_0 = 1$, for each $n$ there will be

- $a_{n-1}$ tilings ending in an $A$ block.
- $b_{n-2}$ tilings ending in a $B$ block.
- $a_{n-3}$ tilings ending in a $C$ block, and similarly for $D$.
- $a_{n-4}$ tilings ending in $EG$, and similarly for $HJ$.
- $a_{n-4-2k}$ tilings ending in $EF^kG$, and similarly for $HI^kJ$.

So $$a_n = a_{n-1} + b_{n-2} + 2a_{n-3} + 2\sum_{k \le (n-4)/2} a_{n-4-2k}\\b_n = a_n - b_{n-2}$$

The $b_{n-2}$ term can be replaced by a sum of $a_k$ values to get a recursion in one dimension. Taking the difference between $a_n$ and $a_{n-2}$ results in a simpler recursion formula, having only a summation for the replaced $b_{n-2}$ term. The same trick can be applied a second time to remove this remaining sum, leaving a linear recursion formula in $a_n$ of fixed length. I'll leave the details of it to you.

Comment: +1 nice observation about the recurrence. As a side note, this was from the Zonal Informatics Olympiad 2009, where they were just expecting numerical answers (calculated algorithmically, through pen and paper).

Comment: @CalvinLin - I started by trying to calculate $n=8$ by hand, and quickly decided it would be easier to figure out recursion formulae and do it that way.